# MySQL join for this specific scenario

Tags: mysql, join

I am having a problem with MySQL joins.

#### `Table_A`:

```
 A_id  Cost1  A1_id  Cost2
 1     500     0     200
 1     100     1     100
 1     50      2      60
 1     10      3      50
 2      5      0      10
```

#### `Table_B` (Refers `B_id`: from `Table_A` `A1_id`):

```
 B_id  FName  LName
 1     X      A
 2     Y      B
 3     Z      C
```

#### `Table_C` (Refers `C_id`: from `Table_A` `A_id`):

```
C_id  Towns

 1    Atlanta
 2    NewYork
```

I need to combine all three tables, like the following output:

- I extract the `Towns` that match `(Table_A.A_id=Table_C.C_id)`.
- I extract the `Fname`,`Lname` that match `(table_A.A1_id=Table_b.b_id)`.
- I need to skip the `Towns` if `A1_id != 0`.
- I need to skip the `Fname`,`Lname` if `A1_id == 0`.

The remaining data may either be a value or null, which I specify as '#'.
What would be an efficient MySQL query for the given scenario?

#### Output:

```
A_id  Cost1  A1_id cost2 Fname Lname Towns
1     500     0    200    #     #    Atlanta
1     100     1    100    X     A     #
1      50     2     60    Y     B     #
1      10     3     50    Z     C     #
```

Comment: your output is confusing.  if you want to "skip A1_id == 0", then the 1st line should not be a part of the query output.

Comment: I have to second @enobrev's comment - what does 'skip if A1_id == 0' mean if the example output includes a row with A1_id == 0.

Comment: Also, since A_id = 1 in each row of output, why does Atlanta not appear in each row of output?

Comment: Now I explained all will I get Response?

Comment: Maybe...it took some spotting what had changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a UNION of two distinct queries to me.  I'm going to assume that the ID columns never contain negative values.

```
SELECT A.A_id, A.Cost1, A.A1_id, A.Cost2, B.Fname, B.Lname, C.Town
    FROM Table_A AS A
              INNER JOIN Table_B AS B ON A.A1_id = B.B_id
         LEFT OUTER JOIN Table_C AS C ON A.A_id  = C.C_id
    WHERE A.A1_id != 0
      AND C.C_id < 0
UNION
SELECT A.A_id, A.Cost1, A.A1_id, A.Cost2, B.Fname, B.Lname, C.Town
    FROM Table_A AS A
         LEFT OUTER JOIN Table_B AS B ON A.A1_id = B.B_id
              INNER JOIN Table_C AS C ON A.A_id  = C.C_id
    WHERE A.A1_id = 0
      AND B.B_id < 0;
```

I'm not completely confident about that formulation.  There's a chance that the conditions on B.B_id < 0 and C.C_id < 0 need to be associated with the corresponding ON clauses.

There's also a decent chance that using two left outer joins in a single SELECT with appropriate OR'd filters would achieve the correct result.

Answer (score 6):

I think it should be something like this.

```
select A_id, Cost1,  A1_id, cost2, Fname, Lname, Towns
from Table_A
left join Table_B on table_A.A1_id = Table_b.b_id
left join Table_C on Table_A.A_id  = Table_C.C_id
```

Comment: +1 for buying beer suggestion, maybe they could add that to the bounty system?

Comment: Haha, yes, like the wordpress plugin 'buy me a beer'

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, it should be:

```
select fname, lname, towns
from table_a, table_b table_c
where table_a.a_id = table_c.c_id
  and table_a.a1_id = table_b.b_id
  and table_a.a1_id <> 0;
```

Comment: Your query will return 0 rows. To get a table like the example you need left joins.